# 'no member nameType' error implementing NSLinguisticTagger in a in Swift 3.2 project

Tags: swift, macos, machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to use NSLinguisticTagger in a Swift 3.2 project for macOS.

This code works fine in Swift 4

```
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.nameType], options: 0) // edited
```

But, gives the error:

> Type 'String' has no member 'nameType' // edited

[image]

in the Swift 3.2 project. I tried to follow old NSLinguisticTagger tutorials but I can't find a replacement for the '.name' part. Is possible to fix this or I have to update the project to Swift 4?

[NSLinguisticTagger Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger)

[NSHipster NSLinguisticTagger 2012 Tutorial](http://nshipster.com/nslinguistictagger/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I need to apologize that I first wrote an answer without confirming my settings are really right. The following descriptions updated based on the settings which I believe correct.
(Xcode 9.2, target Swift Version set to 3.2. Changing the project Swift Version does not affect the target Swift Version, oh, my shame...)

---

When you want to work with old Swift versions, some Swift-friendly wrapper types are not available and APIs and constants are imported from Objective-C world with simple rules. In such cases, you need to re-interpret Objective-C versions of references with such rules in mind.

[`NSLinguisticTagScheme`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagscheme?language=objc)

As you see in the linked article above, `NSLinguisticTagScheme` as just a typealias of `String` and the constants are named as `NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameType` as in the article in your question's link. They are imported as-is in old Swift versions.

So, this compiles in Swift 3.2:

```
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameType], options: 0)
```

(Still, I strongly recommend you to move to Swift 4. As Apple's official references are based on the latest version of Swift, it's Swift 4.)

Comment: Hi OOPer, thank you for your replay, actually I made an error in the code of the question replacing '.nameType' with '.name'. Now I fixed the question.

Comment: @Cue, actually the code with `.nameType` works fine in my test project. Are you really using **Swift 3.2**? Aren't you using Swift 3.0 or 3.1 (or older) with Xcode 8?

Comment: In TARGETS > App > Basic > 'Swift Language Version' is chosen Swift 3.2 but actually I don't know if it shows is the correct info. Working in a copy, some days ago, I tried to upgrade the project but there where some things I didn't knowm to get a complete conversion, so I decided to whait until all resources online are updated. Xcode 9.1.

Comment: @Cue, I have updated my Xcode 9 to Xcode 9.2 soon after released, so I do not see how your env is being. But I recommend you to upgrade your Xcode to the latest 9.2. As I wrote above, the code using `.nameType` compiles both in Swift 3.2 and 4, with correctly installed Xcode 9.2.

Comment: @Cue, sorry to make you take extra time with my mistakes, but I found that I was mis-configuring my project settings. I'll soon update my answer based on the actual behavior in Xcode 9.2/Swift Version 3.2.

Comment: @Cue, done. Again sorry for making you confused with my mistakes. I hope my updated answer can be some help of you.

Comment: @ OOPer thank you so much for your answer! I really appreciated your help.